# Optimize query for retrieving records created 100 days ago

Tags: salesforce

I am using below query to get records created 100 days ago and then deleting them.

```
list<Exception__c> exList = [select id from Exception__c where NOT(CreatedDate  = LAST_N_DAYS:100) limit 10000];
system.debug('Exception__c temp fix scList -->'+exList);
delete exList;
```

Can this query be optimized further or is there a better way?

```
list<Exception__c> exList = [select id from Exception__c where NOT(CreatedDate  = LAST_N_DAYS:100) limit 10000];
system.debug('Exception__c temp fix scList -->'+exList);
delete exList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you want to avoid using negative conditions in your query so that it is selective. In your case I would do

```
Where createddate > last_N_days: 100
```